# Why would SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters not call its completionBlock on iOS 8.0.2 for Apple App Testers?

Tags: ios8, in-app-purchase, xcode6, storekit, itunes-store

My latest app update got rejected by Apple because their testers indicated that they can't buy songs with my app. In particular, it looks like the SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters never calls its completionBlock in my code. Everything works fine for me in development.

What am I missing:

- the song id should be correct: I asked the testers to check that the country of their device's iTunes Store is the same country as the one I used to get the iTunes song ID from the iTunes API (both "US"), so the ID should work perfectly
- I also checked that they were connected to the web before calling the loadProductWithParameters

What else could it be?

Comment: could just be that iOS8 SKStoreProductViewController is buggy piece of crap. 8.1

Comment: lol Even though the Apple testing team never explicitly confirmed it, it turns out this problem is most probably due to bad connectivity and/or low device memory.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the completion block of `[SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock:]` is never called on iOS8 if the music item you're looking for is *not available on your country's iTunes Store*.

Personally, I would have used the `error` of the completion handler to communicate that, but I guess never calling you back is another way of saying the same thing.

At least you can work around this by using the [iTunes Search API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to look for an item that *is* available in your region or to take different steps when it isn't.

Comment: Actually, not calling the completionBlock should be considered a bug from Apple's part...

Comment: I agree, I think the OP was being sarcastic.

Comment: @ZuYuan I still experience it on 8.4

Comment: I've filed a bug report to Apple `rdar://22127487`

Comment: Apple response: duplicate of issue 19220228 (available on rdar)

Comment: It's still not fixed.

Comment: I get this behavior with an appId for an existing app (my app), but not for another (another of my apps). Very flaky. Very odd way to raise an error.